# SQL Reporting Services: Password Protecting Reports

Tags: sql, windows, reporting-services

I have a series of reports being sent out and when being sent internally (across the domain) users use their windows credentials to access them. However when sending them externally there doesn't appear to be a way to password protect them in the email. I want to put a simple password on them or failing that have it send as a password protected Excel sheet.

Comment: How are external users accessing the SSRS server? Usually it doesn't allow anonymous connections, so I suspect they are using some sort of credential.

Comment: what do you mean by "sending them externally"?, do you mean sending them by email to users out side your domain?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not support creating a password protected Excel file. You should secure the access to the SSRS server at the web service level, and use the permission system built into SSRS for the easiest solution.

Alternately, you can built a application (web or otherwise) to wrap SSRS, and pass calls back into SSRS. Much more complicated, but then you can do whatever you want with permissions.